# Reference Website Properly w/ port 8080 on Ubuntu using Nginx with SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx, .net-core, ssl-certificate, certbot

Good day everyone,

I'm trying to publish my sample ASP.NET Core application on ubuntu 16.04 and the proxy server is Nginx.

My server has SSL Certificate provided by [LetsEncript](https://letsencrypt.org/) Everything is working properly. But when I'm trying to use the web application that serves with the example port 8080, it doesn't work and the nginx page is still showing even I already commented out it on default file.

```
server {
    if ($host = www.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }

    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

[Full default file](https://jsfiddle.net/22frhv1y/1/)

(I needed to non-disclose the exact domain name due to privacy)

By the way, my real domain is working properly and localhost:8080 is running properly inside the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare you location inside the server {} with 443 inside.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

Save your default file then restart your nginx

`sudo systemctl restart nginx`